# iPad UISplitViewController not resizing its larger view on startup?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm developing an iPad application (iOS 4) involving a `UISplitViewController`.  The main feature of my larger (right-side) view controller in the split controller is a `UITableView`.  I've set my table view to auto-resize width and height:

```
_tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

This means that when I rotate and the split view controller comes into play, the VC and table view resize appropriately and the scroll indicator stays visible.  But when I start the app in landscape, the views do not appear to resize, so the scroll bars are not visible.

Here is the logging code in my `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` methods and its results.  Skip down to the bottom if you want for the summary.

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController*)pc
{

    NSLog(@"Table frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(_tableView.frame));
    NSLog(@"Self frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)button
{
    NSLog(@"Table frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(_tableView.frame));
    NSLog(@"Self frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
}
```

Starting the app in landscape produces this (**Exhibit A**):

> Table frame: {{0, 223}, {768, 781}}
>
> Self frame: {{0, 20}, {768, 1004}}

Then when I rotate (out of landscape) I get this (**Exhibit B**):

> Table frame: {{0, 223}, {768, 781}}
>
> Self frame: {{321, 0}, {703, 748}}

Starting in portrait and then rotating to landscape gives me this (**Exhibit C**):

> Table frame: {{0, 223}, {768, 781}}
>
> Self frame: {{0, 0}, {768, 1004}}

Then rotate back to portrait (**Exhibit D**):

> Table frame: {{0, 223}, {703, 525}}
>
> Self frame: {{321, 0}, {703, 748}}

It seems to me that:

- A and C should be the same, since they're both essentially rotating out of portrait.  And they are the same, so it's all good.
- B and D should be the same, since they're both essentially rotating out of landscape.  But they're not.  Seems like the auto-resizing is not doing its job here.

It seems that the width of the table should be 703 in landscape and 768 in portrait.  I've tried putting resizing code to set this in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, both these methods, etc. and nothing seems to work right.  What is the normal approach here?

UPDATE 6/15/2011: I solved this by disabling auto-resizing entirely and just setting the frames myself in the two functions above, but I'm still curious if there's a common practice to solve this problem.